# Turn off a Android Service when the user is not on the their home screen!

Tags: android

I need to turn a App / Widget Service off when a user isn't on their homescreen and on / update when they are. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually a declined request in AOSP.
See details here - http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=6393